# An Activity removes the app from recent apps list

Tags: android

I'm developing a SDK with a single Activity that's started with the following flags:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
```

Everything works as expected (i.e. there's a single instance of the Activity that receives all Intents; the user can't navigate back to it) except for one case.
If I start the Activity & then finish the one that started it, the app disappears from the recent apps list.
How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: this may be help you `android:taskAffinity="com.yourpackage.YourActivity"`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `android:taskAffinity="org.example.app"` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Becuase of this flag its not appearing.

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
```

Remove it  and try..

if you mentioned above flag then The App will not shown in the recent Apps list..